# Why does the following program give a error?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, constants, command-line-arguments

Why does the following program give a warning?

**Note**: Its obvious that sending a normal pointer to a function requiring const pointer does not give any warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void sam(const char **p) { }
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    sam(argv);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error,

```
In function `int main(int, char **)':
passing `char **' as argument 1 of `sam(const char **)' 
adds cv-quals without intervening `const'
```

Comment: Is your compiler reporting an error or a warning?  (and, if it is reporting just a warning, what compiler are you using?  It _should_ report an error)

Comment: @James: My compiler[gcc version 2.95.3] is throwing an error. Will edit the question right away. Thanks for the notification.

Comment: @Prabhu:  Ah, ok.  I had initially thought it might be an old version of Visual C++ (_not that I think Visual C++ is lacking in its standards conformance... not at all... nope..._).

Comment: I'm no C++ expert but I will note that your compiler is almost 10 years old.  :-)

Comment: @Ken: Yes Ken. I'm in office right now and here they use this version.

Comment: I am using gcc 4.1.2 (released February 13, 2007), and it gives me a Warning?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code violates const correctness.

The issue is that this code is fundamentally unsafe because you could inadvertently modify a const object.  The C++ FAQ Lite has an excellent example of this in the answer to ["Why am I getting an error converting a `Foo**` → `Foo const**`?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17)

```
class Foo {
 public:
   void modify();  // make some modify to the this object
 };

 int main()
 {
   const Foo x;
   Foo* p;
   Foo const** q = &p;  // q now points to p; this is (fortunately!) an error
   *q = &x;             // p now points to x
   p->modify();         // Ouch: modifies a const Foo!!
   ...
 }
```

(Example from Marshall Cline's C++ FAQ Lite document, [www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/))

You can fix the problem by const-qualifying both levels of indirection:

```
void sam(char const* const* p) { }
```